# Limit page reload on ajax call with GET request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

In my app if URL has certain $_GET parameter I want to update session and reload page once after this AJAX update and following is my code.

```
if($_GET['something']){
   //do something
   $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "localhost/example/ajaxpage.php",
            data: {
                foo: foo_test,
                bar: bar_test,
            },
            success: function (data) {
                window.location.reload();
            }
        });
}
```

but on page reload it get $_GET again so page is being reloaded repeatedly. How can I fix this so that the page reloads only once after the AJAX update.

Comment: unset the value of $_GET['something']

Comment: Use window.location.href instead of reload and pass the URL without the query parameter

Answer (score 0):

Replace

`window.location.reload();`

With

`window.location.href = window.location.origin;` OR use precise `URL` here.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `relaoad()` you can specify the URL in `window.location.href`

```
if($_GET['something']){
   //do something
   $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?= $HOMEPAGE_ROOT; ?>/example/ajaxpage.php",
            data: {
                foo: foo_test,
                bar: bar_test,
                action: 'reload'
            },
            success: function (data) {
                window.location.href = window.location.origin;
            }
        });
}
```

Here you can use `window.location.origin` or your own url in which `something` is not as a get parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Check along with that session variable like this:

```
if($_GET['something'] && isset($_SESSION['test']))
```

or with the value of session.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code

```
       <?php 
        if($_GET['something'] & !isset($_GET['flag'])){
        ?>
            <script>
           //do something
           $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "localhost/example/ajaxpage.php",
                    data: {
                        foo: foo_test,
                        bar: bar_test,
                    },
                    success: function (data) {

                        window.location.href ="Your Url"?something=xyz&flag=1; 
                    }
                });
            </script>
            <?php 
        }
        ?>
```